# Swift label not fitting text correctly

Tags: swift, text, resize, uilabel

I'm trying create a label which will be able to display different movie titles of differing sizes. When I use the code below

```
lbl.numberOfLines = 3
lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
lbl.minimumScaleFactor = 0.05
```

I get the issue of longer words being split into multiple lines

**See the issue below:**

**1st screen shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

**When I use this code:**

```
lbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
lbl.numberOfLines = 3
lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
lbl.minimumScaleFactor = 0.05
```

I get the issue of words being missed out(the label is supposed to display the text "What's Love Got to Do With It")

**See the issue below:**

**2nd screen shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

**The label has a simple set of constraints**

```
lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countdownLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
lbl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnStackView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
lbl.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
lbl.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Setting `minimumScaleFactor` works as expected only if `numberOfLines` is set to `1`. [This](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/UILabel-FontSizeToFit/blob/master/Swift/UILabel_FontSizeToFit/UILabel%2BFontSizeToFit.swift) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screen Shot]

Use option-return when typing in the little box in Interface Builder to insert a line feed (\n). In Interface Builder's Label attributes, set # Lines = 0.

Select the label and then change Lines property to 0.

like in the above image, and then use \n in your string for line break.

Answer (score 0):

You select the label and then in the attributes inspector in the LINES property you leave it at 0 and the AUTOSHRINK property you leave it set to (minimum font scale)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHms4.png)